# Grafana stats panel how to add a plus symbol

Tags: grafana

I have created a stats panel on my dashboard in grafana that has three values; 1 current value, 1 value that represent different from previous week and 1 value that show difference from past month.

The problem that I experience and want to solve is that when there is a positive number in the 2 values that represent the differences there is no plus symbol. There is a minus symbol in front of negative numbers, but I also want a plus symbol in front of the positive numbers.

I've been searching in the settings and also looked to grafana community to see if there is any solution for this, but I cannot find any. Maybe it's not possible? I've also tried to configure my query in order to add the symbol but I don't get it to work.

Comment: I don't think Grafana supports this. Consider using colour-coding to denote numbers sign

Comment: @markalex thank you for your answer. Then it was as I feared. I have used colour-coding but wanted to make it extra clear for the user with the extra layer. Had a meeting today and apparently it was not clear enough haha (they wanted a plus symbol).

EDIT: I'll try other ways to make it more clear what the stat shows and the thought behind.

Comment: You may generate numeric value as string with plus sign. But that introduces other problems, e.g. some features need numeric, not string value.